# How can I query to see if all records in a child model have the same value for an attribute?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

First off, I know this is really basic stuff for most of you but I'm still learning and I would appreciate any help.

I have a boolean column in my child table. I am trying to query all the child records associated with a parent to see whether the value of the boolean column is true for all those child records or not.

What I have now is this:

```
  if Parent.children.count(:conditions => [ 'boolean_column = ?', true ]) == Parent.children.count
    return true
```

My logic with that being that if the count of all the associated child records is equal to the count of the associated child records where the boolean column is true, then that should return true, but of course it doesn't work.

What is the rails way of doing this, if there is one?

Comment: What DBMS you are using MySQL/Postgresql? What is your Rails version/

Comment: I'm using Postgresql and Rails 4.2.6

Comment: Can you try `Children.group(:boolean_column).where(parent_id: 12).count(:boolean_column)[false].blank?` ? Let me know if you get any error

Comment: This returned false. I then went and edited the boolean value for the child record and it returned true in that case. If the record has a nil value this would probably return as true, am I right?

Comment: Here the idea is, when all boolean field will have true value, the query will give {false: 2}, when all false, then {true: 2} and when there is a mix then u will get {false: 1, true: 1}.. so you will be looking for the absent of false key. make sense?

Comment: I understand that this query looks for the absence of false and that makes sense. However a record with a nil value in that column returns the same as a record with a true value in that column. I just tried with a nil value and it also returned 'true' because there is no false value in the column. There were no numbers after the result to differentiate between them.

Comment: Your boolean field should store either `true` or `false`. if you are storing something else, please fix the source. That way you can save lot of extra processing.

Comment: probably we are misundersting..each other. can you show the output of `Children.group(:boolean_column).where(parent_id: 12).count(:boolean_column)` ?

Comment: This returned: {true=>1, false=>1} which is correct as I now have one true value and one false value in the boolean column.

Comment: ok, always make sure your DB column have either true or false.. nothing else. All other noise you will be able to kill there itself. Just 1 guard. Got it? :D

Comment: I will have to make that column null:false in this case.

Comment: yeah that is what you want by adding a migration

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to help me figure this out. I really appreciate it!

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this by doing only 1 query. But to do, you need to make sure first that the boolean column should never have `NULL`, except `true` or `false`. So adding *NOT NULL* constraint will make sure that column will never have NULL. After that you can run the below query:

```
hash = Children.
  group(:boolean_column).
  where(parent_id: 12).
  count(:boolean_column)
```

`12` should be replaced by your actual id of the parent. Now, do check if `hash` has the `false` as a key, like `hash.has_key?(false)`. If there is no `false` key, you can assert that all children has `true` to the boolean column.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it as

```
Parent.children.where("boolean_column = ?", true).count == Parent.children.count
```

Comment: That does 2 query. It can be written in 1 query as I said above.